# Aliasing fields using partial object syntax + array hydrator in doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there any way to alias fields when using [partial object syntax](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) in Doctrine 2?

I know I can do this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('user')->select([
     'user.id AS id',
     'user.firstName AS first_name',
     'user.lastName AS last_name',
     'user.email AS email',
     'user.dateCreated AS date_created'
])->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

However I need to use the partial object syntax in order for doctrine to retrieve the result in a nested relational heirarchy:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('team')
    ->select('PARTIAL team.{id, name, dateCreated}, s, PARTIAL e.{id, name}')
    ->innerJoin('team.session', 's')
    ->innerJoin('s.event', 'e')
    ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

I dug around in `Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ArrayHydrator` but didn't see any hooks or anything, and it doesn't look like Doctrine has a `postSelect` event or something that would allow me to implement my own mutation.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very efficient, but I ended up [subclassing the ArrayHydrator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) and mutating the keys myself.

Hopefully there is a better way, if not I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not just about alias, it's also about bracket. Basically, [Partial object syntax](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) is very poor and does not allow aliases or brackets. It expects for a coma or the end of the list, and everything else will throw a syntax error.

I wanted to retrieve a partial object collection using a SUM() function like this

```
public function findByCompetition(array $competition)
{
    $competitionField = $competition['field'] ?? 'Id';
    $competitionValue = $competition['value'] ?? 0;

    $teamsCompStatsByComp = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('partial t.{Id, competitionId, competitionOldId, teamId, teamOldId, SUM(goalsAttempted) goalsAttempted}')
        ->where('t.'.$competitionField.' = ?1')
        ->groupBy('t.teamId')
        ->orderBy('t.Id', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('1', $competitionValue)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    return new ArrayCollection($teamsCompStatsByComp);
}
```

**But got the same error**

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 85: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE, got '('

**I had to retrieve data as an array, use IDENTITY() on Foreign Key, then manually hydrate my entities**

```
public function findByCompetition(array $competition)
{
    $competitionField = $competition['field'] ?? 'Id';
    $competitionValue = $competition['value'] ?? 0;

    $teamsCompStatsByComp = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.Id, IDENTITY(t.competitionId) competitionId, t.competitionOldId, IDENTITY(t.teamId) teamId, t.teamOldId, SUM(goalsAttempted) goalsAttempted')
        ->where('t.'.$competitionField.' = ?1')
        ->groupBy('t.teamId')
        ->orderBy('t.Id', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('1', $competitionValue)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    foreach ($teamsCompStatsByComp as $key => $teamCompStats) {
        $teamsCompStatsByComp[$key] = new TeamStatistics($teamCompStats);
    }

    return new ArrayCollection($teamsCompStatsByComp);
}
```

I think we should open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues) to improve partial syntax behavior.