# symfony createQueryBuilder leftjoin with certain selected fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join

I made a query for selecting certain fields together with a leftjoin.

However I cannot get it to work both at the same time (have a leftjoin and certain selected fields).

```
$query = $em->getRepository(Product::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p, p.slug, p.price, p.title_x AS title, pc')
    ->leftJoin('p.productimgs', 'pc')
    ->getQuery();
```

I call the array with

```
{% for item in article.productimgs %}
```

but i get the  error: Key "productimgs" for array with keys "0, slug, price, title" does not exist

I also tried to call it with the function

```
{% for item in article.getProductimgs() %}
```

but then i get this error : Impossible to invoke a method ("getProductimgs") on an array.

I am not so good with doctrine / query building.
The productimages is a onetomany relation in the product entity.
it's a symfony 5 project

All help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mixing the entities and specific columns in the `select` the hydrated results will actually be arrays and not `Product`s. You can see it's structure with

```
{{ dump(article) }}
```

If you just want to eager load the related product images in the *one* query use

```php
$query = $em->getRepository(Product::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p, pc')
    ->leftJoin('p.productimgs', 'pc')
    ->getQuery();
```

This will hydrate the results as `Product`s so you can access its properties by the Twig shorthands or as functions:

```
{{ article.slug }}
{{ article.getSlug() }}
```

If you access the `Product`'s images it will not execute a new database query to fetch them since you added them to the `select` part and they were already hydrated into the result objects:

```
{{ article.productimgs }}
{{ article.getProductimgs() }}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for you feedback ! I didn't know the background of this so much. I would like to only select some columns, and also rename them but also access the related productimages in 1 query.  How do i do this then?

Comment: What are your reasons for doing that? If you want only fetch a subset of columns use the [partial object syntax](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax): `select('partial p.{id,slug,price,title_x}, pc')`.

If you want to alias a column add a respective function to the entity: `Product::getTitle()` -> `return $this->title_x`.
But there is no way to combine partial syntax with aliases, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441326/aliasing-fields-using-partial-object-syntax-array-hydrator-in-doctrine-2

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Also not possible then to combine the alias together with a join (left, inner)?  Reasons, I didn't want to use all columns and the alias is meant for using it in a condition.

Comment: @Missblues You could try using a data transfer obejct but I don't know if you can use objects there. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax